# Finding common values in column A for each instance of a value in column B in Excel

Tags: excel

I have excel data in columns A and B such as

```
**Column A**    **Column B** 
 System A     System N 
 System B     System N 
 System C     System N 
 System B     System M 
 System D     System M
 System C     System O
```

I am trying to display the number of systems that are common in Column A for each unique value in column B, effectively the commonality between each set of values in column A for each value in column B

I tried using COUNTIF but wasn't able to get the right match.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question but COUNTIF should do it. i.e. if you put this formula in cell C2 = COUNTIF($A:$A, $B1) and extend down it will count the number of times B1 is in column A, then C3 will be count of B2 in column A..

Comment: In my example data above, the common values for System N and System M are System B from from Column A, and System C is common for Systems N and O. 

The same systems may be in both columns but more likely not.

Comment: Still confused sorry, can u show your expected results plz

Comment: Expected result: Consider that these are products and locations in column A and Column B. I am looking for the products that are common to different locations. So Location A might have products IPod, IPhone and iTV. Location B has products IPhone and ICar. return iCar. Then repeat the same for Location A and C, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **pivot table** may help you with this.
You can make a cross-tab with `ColumnA` as columns, `ColumnB` as rows, `ColumnA` as Values. Of course 'pivot' it like you need.

An example how it can look like is shown in picture.
[image]

Settings for pivot table:
[image]